# Microsoft CRM dynamics - Autofill bug

Tags: dynamics-crm, autofill

I am using Microsoft CRM dynamics and when I am typing inside an empty cell I am getting an autofill bug. I have recorded a small video in order to show the issue. Just to explain a little bit, while I an hovering over the empty cell, it gives me some older names I have used. If I select one of those old names and try to correct one word from the title (eg. old word is "second", new word is "third"), the time I take the mouse to the next cell it will give to the title the old word again. Please check the link to understand the situation.   https://streamable.com/90skrk

[image]

Regarding the browser, I am using google chrome but it keeps happening on Microsoft Edge as well. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is happening in all input fields or only with case title field? Which chrome version you are using? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: The issue is not with the CRM but with the browser, there is something introduced by MS 'Disable most recent used items' which works only with look up field.

Comment: Hello @AliasgarRajpiplawala, it keeps happening to all the fields that are empty and wait input by the user (not the cells with drop down selection). The chrome version I am using is 94.0.4606.54 (the latest). I have tried clearing the cache.

Comment: Try in another machine and check, also check for any extensions. As I had mentioned the issue is with the browser or machine and not with CRM.

Comment: I will try the above you stated Aliasgar. Thank you for the support given.